# Date string to epoch in bash

Tags: shell, date, date-utility

How can I get the epoch if I have a string in the following format?
`1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM`
The following does not work:

```
$ date -j  '1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM' +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'  
date: illegal time format
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the input format with `-f`:

```
$ date -jf '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p' '1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM' '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
01/30/2017 11:14:55
```

What goes after `+` is the *output* format. If you want the epoch time, that would be `+%s`.

(note that there's nothing `bash`-specific in that code. That code would be parsed the same in any shell, even non-Bourne-like ones. `date` is not a `bash` builtin command, here it's the `date` command found on the file system, specifically one that supports those `-f`/`-j` BSD extensions. On non-BSD systems that command is likely not to work regardless of whether the shell is `bash` or other. Some shells like `zsh` or `ksh93` have time-parsing capabilities built in but not `bash`)

Comment: What I want is to parse that string and get the epoch i.e. a numeric value. I thought I could do that with `date`. Your answer just prints the string back. Unless I misunderstood what I need to do

Comment: @Jim Change the last argument to `'+%s'` and you'll get number of seconds since the Epoch UTC.